# sms code not coming from pyrogram for new accounts

Tags: python, authentication, pyrogram

When I call in pyrogram function "send code" to new account, i don't get it. But i get it for already created accounts in telegram's message. Here is a part of a code:

```
phone_number = "+79111443505"
    client = Client(":popo", app_id, api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    sent_code_info = await client.send_code(phone_number=phone_number,force_sms=True)
    print(sent_code_info)
    phone_code = input("Please enter your phone code: ")  # Sent phone code using last function
```

sent code is equal: [image]

And, if i try to create account from official telegram app it work's fine, but does not git it if it send from my code.